# Are there open standards for storing multi-modal routing graphs?

Tags: routing, transportation, standards

I'm looking for any **open** standards (or maybe best practices) for storing multi-modal routing graphs, eg. info for pedestrian, bike, public transport and car routing, etc.

Every data provider seems to have their own format. My goal is to convert data from different providers into a common standardized format and then build applications from there.

Comment: [TRB](http://trb.org) is one of the goto organizations in North America. I'm not sure how influential they are in Europe. Here's their [TransXML](http://www.trb.org/Main/Blurbs/158531.aspx) document. I'm not sure if it covers what you need and also I'm not sure if it's widely used either.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot point you to any standards, but I would take a look at [OpenTripPlanner](http://opentripplanner.com/learn) and see what you can learn from their community.

OTP is an open-source, [multi-modal routing system](https://github.com/openplans/OpenTripPlanner/wiki/) that the public transportation agency ([TriMet](http://rtp.trimet.org/#/)) in the city of Portland, Oregon uses and contributes to.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out the General (or Google!) Transit Feed Specification at http://www.gtfs-data-exchange.com/ as an option.

Comment: If I interpret the site correctly, this only covers public transport, right?